# How to trim whitespace in formula that is looks at data from a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula

`=B46+C46-D46-SUMIFS($G$2:$G$42, $A$2:$A$42, A46, $D$2:$D$42,"?uction*", $F$2:$F$42,"n")-SUMIFS($G$2:$G$42, $A$2:$A$42, A46, $D$2:$D$42,"Attorney")`

I would like to be sure that any white space is removed from column `D` before it is compared to the string "Attorney". Could someone show me how to update this formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but see if this works

```
=B46+C46-D46-SUMIFS($G$2:$G$42, $A$2:$A$42, A46, $D$2:$D$42,"?uction*", $F$2:$F$42,"n")-SUMIFS($G$2:$G$42, $A$2:$A$42, A46, Arrayformula(trim($D$2:$D$42)),"Attorney")
```